# Link sharing for Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, file-sharing

I'm about to ask a very basic question, where I asked in another community group but didn't get any response.  Seeing how much more active SO is, figured I should ask here.

I have a Spreadsheet on Google Sheet that I have granted viewing access to people. However, I also want to give certain people Edit access. But it seemed like if I changed the access type during the link share option, then everyone would be able to edit it.

Basically I want to share the sheet, but with the option of view only, and view & edit. And is it possible to grant someone editing access without having them to sign in.?

Answer (score 0):

set your spreadsheet as **View** for public and then add people who are allowed to edit it under:

[image: 0]

[image]

Comment: It's not possible if the edit access is given to users without signing in, right?